# How to set the space between columns provided by the `multcol` package?

Tags: multicol

According to [the `multcol` package's user manual](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf) (2017/4/15, p. 3)

> The space between columns is controlled by the length parameter `\columnsep`.

Unfortunately, there is no example showing how to use this parameter.

How can the space between columns be set?

---

**Attempted solution**

I tried [@Troy's suggestion below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374376/how-to-set-the-space-between-columns-provided-by-the-multcol-package?noredirect=1#comment925943_374376), as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0cm}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

but the resulting pdf file is the same whether or not the line `\setlength{\columnsep}{0cm}` is commented out, namely

[image: \columnsep = 0cm]

Comment: `\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}`?

Comment: It is the same parameter, set the same way as the standard twocolumn option.

Comment: @Troy: `\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}` has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @EvanAad Provide a minimal working example, please.

Comment: @Troy: I've added a minimal working example.

Comment: @EvanAad place the `\setlength{...}` before beginning the `multicols` envt.